# PHP error with Computed field

Tags: 7, entities

here is my code:

```
$nid = $entity->field_empf_number['und']['0']['nid'];  
$result = db_query("SELECT MAX(entity_id) FROM field_data_field_empf_number WHERE field_empf_number_nid = $nid")->fetchField();  
if (isset($result)){  
  $n = $result ;  
  $node = node_load($n);  
  $node->field_empf_stat['und']['0']['value'] = 'off';  //list field  
  node_save($node);  
}  
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $result;`
```

when add new node (if there is previous node i mean the if statement return true ) this error message show up:

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached,
>   aborting! in C:\wamp\www\finance\includes\database\database.inc on
>   line 429

I googled but i did not found any answers.

Comment: I guess you are calling this in one of the node hooks which will become infinite loop because of node_save in the code !!

Comment: are you telling me to write "node_Save" function out of the if statement?

Comment: I mean where is above code written ??

Comment: What Anil means is that the computed field is probably computed when a node is saved. Since you save a node (again) the computed field is computed again, which causes a node to be saved, which causes the computed field to be saved, and so on, forever.

Comment: but this problem caused when creating new node

Comment: Where did you put the computed field code? Did you put it in ha hook or in side the field?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the node_save($node) to drupal_register_shutdown_function('node_save', $node). It will remove the old node saving process from the actual node saving. 
But I don't think, that type of code should have place within a computed field. The computed field good to modify the *same* field. It isn't designed for modifying other data of your system.
These code should be in a custom module in hook_node_presave().

Answer (score 0):

The code for the computed field should preferrably be placed in your module, not in your database. This will make your code much easier to debug so the abovementioned errors won't happen.

Use the [computed field hook](http://www.urbaninsight.com/2012/07/30/working-drupal-computed-field-module) - here is a nice ([tutorial](http://www.urbaninsight.com/2012/07/30/working-drupal-computed-field-module)).

[Here](https://drupal.org/node/126522) are some code examples.